# Flying with expired passport from Australia to Israel

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, israeli-citizens, australian-residents, expired

We live in Australia (**not** citizens yet, only permanent residents) and plan to fly to Israel (we are Israeli citizens) with Emirates.
Unfortunately our kids passports are expired and Israel embassy are on a strike and unable to issue us new passports.

I've confirmed that we will be able to enter Israel with expired passports (as we are citizens) and also Emirates (airline) doesn't have a problem with that.

The only concern is with Australia's border control.
Any one had a similar issue? Will border control in Australia deny our exit?

Note: we plan to issue new passports for our kids while we are in Israel.

Thanks

Comment: I think this is enough of an edge case that the only way to get an answer would be by trying to call them. My personal guess is that their only concern on exit is to find the record of the visa or ETA they are on, but this is really just a guess.

Comment: indeed, countries typically don't care about the status of your passport when you're leaving, as long as you have no criminal proceedings going on against you and no outstanding fines to pay they typically are happy to see you go.

Comment: @jwenting I think that's an oversimplification.  EG Airlines do care about the status of your passport, because they don't want to put you on a flight where you can't be admitted to the country at the other end.  And an expired passport may preclude you from obtaining a required transit visa depending on your itinerary.  However in this particular case the OP has verified with Emirates that it is not a problem.

Comment: @PeterM jwenting wrote "**countries** typically don't care...". Indeed airlines care (because the destination or transit countries care), but the **country** you're leaving from (i.e. the border control officer at the exit passport control) shouldn't care much. But I've never been in that situation, so I can't say for certain. For all we know, as soon as they scan the passport (to retrieve the immigration record) the system may beep to the end of time and refuse any further processing :-/

Comment: @PeterM country of departure couldn't care less. Country of arrival may care very much, and as the airline can get fined for allowing you on the flight with invalid papers (at least some countries do this) the airline has reason to care as well. E.g. I've left my home country for Canada a few years ago and never had border control check my passport at all (they checked whether my boarding pass was ok for the concourse and whether I had a passport at all only), but the airline checked quite thoroughly, including looking up whether I had a valid ETA (Canada's equivalent to the US ESTA).

Comment: @jwenting yes I know you only mentioned countries.  My point was that it's a oversimplification that only considers one aspect of traveling with an expired passport, when in fact red reality is that there are other factors that come into play in such cases.

Comment: @PeterM OP mentioned he'd already contacted the airline and they said they were ok with it, so that wasn't a topic worthy of mention in this specific case

Comment: @jwenting you mean like how I said yesterday "However in this particular case the OP has verified with Emirates that it is not a problem"

Answer (score 3):

I've asked a friend of mine to check with one of the supervisors at the border control.

It's not official response, however the supervisor mentioned that there will be no issues from their end.

We decided to cancel our flight due to other circumstances.